# Checking if list element in list of lists and returning sublist

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, any

I have two lists

```
list1 = ['B', 'C', 'D']
list2 = [['1', 'A'], ['2', 'B'], ['3', 'D'], ['5', 'C']]
```

and want to return those sublistst of list2 that contain elements of list1.
So far I tried using any:

```
result = []

for l2 in list2:
    if any (item in l2 for item in list1):
        result.append(l2)
```

and a naive approach

```
for l2 in list2:
    for l1 in l1:
        if l1 in l2:
            result.append(l2)
```

But I only managed to repeat empty list.
The result should be

```
result = [['2', 'B'], ['5', 'C']]
```

Not sure, where I'm going wrong. Is there maybe a way using list comprehensions or mixing list comprehensions and 'any' function?

Comment: Where is `['3', 'D']`?

Comment: Your first code snippet should give your expected output, and not empty list. Did you run your code?

Comment: And so does your second code snippet, as well - except for the typo: `for l1 in list1:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have looks correct and works for me locally too:

```
for l2 in list2:
    if any (item in l2 for item in list1):
        result.append(l2)
```

It returns `[['2', 'B'], ['3', 'D'], ['5', 'C']]` which is the expected result right?

Also note that you can speed up your implementation by changing list1 into a set `list1 = set(['B', 'C', 'D'])` and changing the if condition to  `if any (item in list1 for item in l2):`.
This is because `item in list1` is much faster if `list1` is a `set` than a `list`. That's because `set` uses a hashmap under the hood the quickly accesss elements.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
result=[i for i in list2 if any([k in i for k in list1])]
print(result)

[['2', 'B'], ['3', 'D'], ['5', 'C']]
```

Answer (score 0):

If the elements are hashable objects (as in this case with strings), then you can use set intersection:

```
>>> list1 = ['B', 'C', 'D']
>>> list2 = [['1', 'A'], ['2', 'B'], ['3', 'D'], ['5', 'C']]

>>> s = set(list1)
>>> [l for l in list2 if set(l) & s]
[['2', 'B'], ['3', 'D'], ['5', 'C']]
```

If the intersection is empty then this is treated as a false value for the purpose of the `if` filter in the list comprehension.

That said, I cannot reproduce the fact that your (first) code in the question is *not* working for you; it works fine when I try it. Your second code snippet (aside from the typo) has a potential problem of duplicated sublists in the output because you do not `break` from the inner loop after finding the first matching item.